# How to add table and figure label to table number and figure number in list of figures and list of tables?

Tags: texstudio

When I use overleaf by following code:

```
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{figure}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\tablename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{table}
\newcommand\entrynumberwithprefix[2]{#1\enspace#2\hfill}
```

It generates :
[image]

But when I used same code in TexStudio I got following errors:

[image]

How can I solve this problem for TexStudio?

**EDIT**

After first comment's code also , same error
[image]

Comment: Your Error just says, that you are missing \begin{document} and \end{document}, which ist also missing in your Examplecode. DId you just forgot to add them?

Comment: I have added them before \begin{document} in Overleaf and Texstudio. Doesnt work in Texstudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\newpage
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newlength\figurelen
\settowidth\figurelen{Figure}
\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0em} 
\addtolength\cftfignumwidth{\figurelen}
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{Figure }
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}{ \listoffigures}

\newpage
\newlength\tablelen
\settowidth\tablelen{Table}
\renewcommand{\cfttabindent}{0em} 
\addtolength\cfttabnumwidth{\tablelen}
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{Table }
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}{ \listoftables}
\newpage
```

Using this, it generates in TexStudio as described in question.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tocbasic}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{figure}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\tablename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{table}
\newcommand\entrynumberwithprefix[2]{#1\enspace#2\hfill}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
a & b \\ 
\hline 
c & d \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\caption{Hi}
\end{figure}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

The output is then:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I run same code in new Textsudio file same error generates

Comment: @HimalAcharya - TeXstudio is just a front-end to a TeX distribution. Which TeX distribution is installed on your system?

Comment: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1